# Converting char array into byte array and back again

Tags: java, arrays, char, byte

I'm looking to convert a Java char array to a byte array *without creating an intermediate `String`*, as the char array contains a password. I've looked up a couple of methods, but they all seem to fail:

```
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();

byte[] passwordBytes1 = new byte[password.length*2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(passwordBytes1).asCharBuffer().put(password);

byte[] passwordBytes2 = new byte[password.length*2];
for(int i=0; i<password.length; i++) {
    passwordBytes2[2*i] = (byte) ((password[i]&0xFF00)>>8); 
    passwordBytes2[2*i+1] = (byte) (password[i]&0x00FF); 
}

String passwordAsString = new String(password);
String passwordBytes1AsString = new String(passwordBytes1);
String passwordBytes2AsString = new String(passwordBytes2);

System.out.println(passwordAsString);
System.out.println(passwordBytes1AsString);
System.out.println(passwordBytes2AsString);
assertTrue(passwordAsString.equals(passwordBytes1) || passwordAsString.equals(passwordBytes2));
```

The assertion always fails (and, critically, when the code is used in production, the password is rejected), yet the print statements print out password three times. Why are `passwordBytes1AsString` and `passwordBytes2AsString` different from `passwordAsString`, yet appear identical? Am I missing out a null terminator or something? What can I do to make the conversion and unconversion work?

Comment: Why do You want to avoid creating an intermediate String?

Comment: Sun recommends it as best practice: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#PBEEx Strings are immutable, and hence can't be zeroed out like char arrays - instead, your password hangs around in memory for an indeterminate amount of time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `String(byte[])` constructor, which uses the platform default encoding. That's almost *never* what you should be doing - if you pass in "UTF-16" as the character encoding to work, your tests will probably pass. Currently I suspect that `passwordBytes1AsString` and `passwordBytes2AsString` are each 16 characters long, with every other character being U+0000.

Comment: I just tried that (i.e. `String passwordBytes1AsString = new String(passwordBytes1, "UTF-16");`) and there's no change. I also tried checking the length of the strings - `String.length()` returns 8. Would it count U+0000 characters?

Comment: @Scott: Try printing out the lengths of the strings, and the individual characters (as int values). That'll show you where the differences are.

Comment: 112,97,115,115,119,111,114,100 for both the original and the converted ones.

Comment: Have just noticed that I was using the wrong parameters to `equals()` in the assertion. \*facepalm\* Your original supposition was indeed the correct one. Many thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Conversion between char and byte is character set encoding and decoding.I prefer to make it as clear as possible in code.  It doesn't really mean extra code volume:

```
 Charset latin1Charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"); 
 charBuffer = latin1Charset.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)); // also decode to String
 byteBuffer = latin1Charset.encode(charBuffer);                 // also decode from String
```

**Aside:**

java.nio classes and java.io Reader/Writer classes use ByteBuffer & CharBuffer (which use byte[] and char[] as backing arrays). So often preferable if you use these classes directly.  However, you can always do:

```
 byteArray = ByteBuffer.array();  byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);  
 byteBuffer.get(byteArray);       charBuffer.put(charArray);
 charArray = CharBuffer.array();  charBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(charArray);
 charBuffer.get(charArray);       charBuffer.put(charArray);
```

Answer (score 16):

#### Original Answer

```
    public byte[] charsToBytes(char[] chars){
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = charset.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(chars));
        return Arrays.copyOf(byteBuffer.array(), byteBuffer.limit());
    }

    public char[] bytesToChars(byte[] bytes){
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        CharBuffer charBuffer = charset.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
        return Arrays.copyOf(charBuffer.array(), charBuffer.limit());    
    }
```

#### Edited to use StandardCharsets

```
public byte[] charsToBytes(char[] chars)
{
    final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(chars));
    return Arrays.copyOf(byteBuffer.array(), byteBuffer.limit());
}

public char[] bytesToChars(byte[] bytes)
{
    final CharBuffer charBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
    return Arrays.copyOf(charBuffer.array(), charBuffer.limit());    
}
```

Here is a [JavaDoc page for StandardCharsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html).
Note this on the JavaDoc page:

> These charsets are guaranteed to be available on every implementation of the Java platform.

Comment: Nice use of ByteBuffer. However, without it being stated otherwise, the password is Unicode, so StandardCharset.UTF_8 would be better than corrupting the data by reducing it to ASCII.

Comment: You can use any charset you need

Comment: I have edited the post changing from US-ASCII to UTF-8. You are right. The ideea is to keep same encoding. The US-ASCII does not have as many chars as UTF-8, for example - no letters with accents, and if you use first UTF-8 and after US-ASCII you loose some info.

Comment: After storing sensitive data in char[] or byte[]  you need to clear the sensitive data as Andrii explains in usage from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9670279/1582089

Comment: Nice example. But in my case it works with 
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

Answer (score 5):

I would do is use a loop to convert to bytes and another to conver back to char.

```
char[] chars = "password".toCharArray();
byte[] bytes = new byte[chars.length*2];
for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++) {
   bytes[i*2] = (byte) (chars[i] >> 8);
   bytes[i*2+1] = (byte) chars[i];
}
char[] chars2 = new char[bytes.length/2];
for(int i=0;i<chars2.length;i++) 
   chars2[i] = (char) ((bytes[i*2] << 8) + (bytes[i*2+1] & 0xFF));
String password = new String(chars2);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a ByteBuffer and CharBuffer, don't do the simple `.asCharBuffer()`, which simply does an UTF-16 (LE or BE, depending on your system - you can set the byte-order with the `order` method) conversion (since the Java Strings and thus your `char[]` internally uses this encoding).

Use `Charset.forName(charsetName)`, and then its `encode` or `decode` method, or the `newEncoder` /`newDecoder`.

When converting your byte[] to String, you also should indicate the encoding (and it should be the same one).

Answer (score 3):

This is an extension to Peter Lawrey's answer. In order to backward (bytes-to-chars) conversion work correctly for the whole range of chars, the code should be as follows:

```
char[] chars = new char[bytes.length/2];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
   chars[i] = (char) (((bytes[i*2] & 0xff) << 8) + (bytes[i*2+1] & 0xff));
}
```

We need to "unsign" bytes before using (`& 0xff`). Otherwise half of the all possible char values will not get back correctly. For instance, chars within `[0x80..0xff]` range will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of `getBytes()` instead of `toCharArray()`

Replace the line

```
char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
```

with

```
byte[] password = "password".getBytes();
```

Comment: dont use `String#getBytes()` without specifying an encoding, that gets you into all kinds of portability trouble.

Comment: not appropriate to the use case : this line was just an easy way to get char[] in this example.

Answer (score 1):

When you use GetBytes From a String in Java, The return result will depend on the default encode of your computer setting.(eg: StandardCharsetsUTF-8 or StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1etc...).

So, whenever you want to getBytes from a String Object. Make sure to give a encode . like :

```
String sample = "abc";
Byte[] a_byte = sample .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Let check what has happened with the code.
In java, the String named sample , is stored by Unicode. every char in String stored by 2 byte.

```
sample :  value: "abc"   in Memory(Hex):  00 61 00 62 00 63
        a -> 00 61
        b -> 00 62
        c -> 00 63
```

But, When we getBytes From a String, we have

```
Byte[] a_byte = sample .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
//result is : 61 62 63
//length: 3 bytes

Byte[] a_byte = sample .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)  
//result is : 00 61 00 62 00 63        
//length: 6 bytes
```

In order to get the oringle byte of the String. We can just read the Memory of the string and get Each byte of the String.Below is the sample Code:

```
public static byte[] charArray2ByteArray(char[] chars){
    int length = chars.length;
    byte[] result = new byte[length*2+2];
    int i = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ;j<chars.length;j++){
        result[i++] = (byte)( (chars[j] & 0xFF00) >> 8 );
        result[i++] = (byte)((chars[j] & 0x00FF)) ;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usages:

```
String sample = "abc";
//First get the chars of the String,each char has two bytes(Java).
Char[] sample_chars = sample.toCharArray();
//Get the bytes
byte[] result = charArray2ByteArray(sample_chars).

//Back to String.
//Make sure we use UTF_16BE. Because we read the memory of Unicode of  
//the String from Left to right. That's the same reading 
//sequece of  UTF-16BE.
String sample_back= new String(result , StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention `getBytes`, so this isn't really relevant. Are you trying to comment on one of the other answers?

Comment: Just want to declare that the usages of  String 's getBytes Function. And what should be taking care of when using new String(Byte[]) . Hope it helps.