# How to get the bytes of a control character in Java

Tags: java, character

I need to get the bytes of the control character STX (02h) to append to a stream I need to send to a controller board.

How do I get the bytes of the STX control character in Java?

Comment: Would this post help you out?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513144/converting-char-to-byte

Comment: STX is a single character in ASCII, not represented by the literal "STX".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytes of the control character depend on the encoding the controller board uses. For ASCII:

```
"\u0002".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
```

Note that if you are writing characters to an output stream, you should wrap it with a Writer which is configured with the correct encoding:

```
OutputStream controllerOutputStream;
Charset controllerCharset = StandardCharsets.US_ASCII; // probably ASCII
Writer controllerWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(controllerOutputStream, controllerCharset);

controllerWriter.append('\u0002'); // append a single character
```

Comment: That may or may not work depending on your platform's default charset, and whether the controller board uses the same.

Comment: First, it's `getBytes()`, not `toBytes()`. Second, not in `utf-16`.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard   - This worked - THANX!!!  The board does use that standard ASCII characters.

Comment: @RealSkeptic You're right, of course, I improved my answer.