# Using BCrypt with a char[]

Tags: java, security, hash, char, bcrypt

Around a few hours ago, I enquired on Stack Overflow about methods on how to convert a char[] to an MD5 hash.  A solution was provided, but was thought to be insecure - as outlined by a couple of people: [Generating an MD5 Hash with a char[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560830/generating-an-md5-hash-with-a-char)

Neil Smithline recommended that I make use of BCrypt, but I am unable to use that with char[]'s.

The reason that I am using a char[] for storing the retrieved password from a login form is because `.getPassword()` supports only char[].

```
        char[] passwordChars = passwordInputField.getPassword();
        String hashed = BCrypt.hashpw(passwordChars, BCrypt.gensalt(12));
```

Currently, I am trying to use the above code to generate a hash but as the variable passwordCars is of type a char[], it is not supported by `BCrypt.haspw()`

Now the only reason why I am not using a regular String is because it cannot be cleared from memory.

My question now is - is it possible to somehow use char[]'s with BCrypt?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's kinda a bad idea, but you would need to take the char[] and turn back into a String (based on what I can tell from the api), which seems like a bad design...

Comment: What would you recommend then? MD5 seems insecure, and BCrypt doesn't seem to work with char[]'s.

Comment: Find an implementation that doesn't use String

Comment: Is there anything good that you would recommend?

Comment: I'm no security expert by any means, but about the only issue I know of with md5 is that there is a remote chance that it could generate the same hash value for two different strings. Do you have any more information it's vanutability?

Comment: Okay, you could pull a version from [here](https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt) modify it to use a char[] instead and then post a pull request to solve the problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer - hashing is out for password storage "key extension" is in. [BCrypt and PBKDF2](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/10885) are the standards.

Comment: @NeilSmithline - Any suggestions on what I could do?  Any solutions to use?

Comment: Yes @HrachGhapantsyan, both Java impls of bcrypt that I found take a String as input. As you seem to know, putting the password into a string opens you up to memory attack.

Comment: I just saw an implementation of pbkdf2 which took a String and converted it to a char[] :(

Comment: You can just tweak the functions @MadProgrammer to avoid the String.

Comment: @NeilSmithline It's a shame that the base implementation examples which are demonstrated make such a fundamentally bad mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Java impls of bcrypt that I found take a String as input. As you seem to know, putting the password into a string opens you up to memory attack.

You can use PBKDF2 as well as bcrypt. Both are considered top-notch. There are PBKDF2 Java code samples [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/22/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/) and [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode). Both allow passing a `char[]` to the functions.

To answer an implicit question from the comments, the reason that you don't use MD5 or any hash is that they are just too fast. Brute forcing passwords with special hardware becomes possible with them. Bcrypt and PBKDF2 are designed to be slow.

Even if you're going to use a hash (which I recommend against), you must salt it. Reversing unsalted password hashes is trivial (see [this tool](https://crackstation.net/)).

The [CrackStation's reference](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on password storage is a good general reference.

Comment: If you recommend not using hashes, then what would you recommend using?

Comment: Also, for the second example, will I need to modify any of the source code and could you provide a usage example?

Answer (score 4):

So, based on the implementation presented at https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt, you need to change the `hashpw` and `checkpw` methods to accept `char[]` instead of `String`

Probably, the hardest part is in `hashpw`...

```
    try {
        passwordb = (password + (minor >= 'a' ? "\000" : "")).getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        throw new AssertionError("UTF-8 is not supported");
    }
```

The easiest solution would be to wrap the `char[]` back into a `String`, but we're trying to avoid that.  Instead, based on the highest scoring answer from [Converting char[] to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513144/converting-char-to-byte), we can do something more like...

```
    char[] expanded = password;
    if (minor >= 'a') {
        expanded = Arrays.copyOf(expanded, expanded.length + 1);
        expanded[expanded.length - 1] = '\000';
    }

    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(expanded);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(charBuffer);
    passwordb = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteBuffer.array(), byteBuffer.position(), byteBuffer.limit());
```

The `checkpw` method actually doesn't need any modifications (apart from the parameters), as it uses the `hashpw` method to check the results.

So, testing...

```
// We want the same salt for comparison
String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(12);
String original = BCrypt.hashpw("Testing", salt);
System.out.println(original);
String hash = BCrypt.hashpw("Testing".toCharArray(), salt);
System.out.println(hash);
System.out.println(BCrypt.checkpw("Testing", hash));
System.out.println(BCrypt.checkpw("Testing".toCharArray(), hash));
```

Outputs...

```
$2a$12$KclXlnca78yhcrg1/mNrRepLYqeJE//SRhrh1X3UM7YUQMjY4x8gy
$2a$12$KclXlnca78yhcrg1/mNrRepLYqeJE//SRhrh1X3UM7YUQMjY4x8gy
true
true
```

Now, if you have a GitHub account, you could actually clone the original repo, make the suggested changes and generate a pull requests.  I'd, personally, be temptered to get rid of the `checkpw` and `hashpw` methods which require `String`

I also found [this](http://adambard.com/blog/3-wrong-ways-to-store-a-password/) implementation of the PDKDF2, which uses `String`, but then promptly converted it to a `char[]` ... so, that was VERY simply to change...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question: *yes*, it is possible to use `char[]`s with BCrypt in Java.

The [Bouncy Castle crypto packages for Java](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) added the BCrypt password hashing algorithm (using the String format and the Base64 encoding of the reference implementation on OpenBSD) in version 1.52 (Mar 2015), **and it only supports `char[]` passwords**.

The relevant method to generate a BCrypt string can be found in the [org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.**OpenBSDBCrypt**](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/OpenBSDBCrypt.html) class and has the following signature:

```
String generate(char[] password,
                byte[] salt,
                int cost)
```

If you'd like to verify in the source code that the `char[]` is preserved without being converted into a String, the relevant classes are [OpenBSDBcrypt](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/OpenBSDBCrypt.java), [Strings](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/util/Strings.java) and [BCrypt](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/generators/BCrypt.java).