# Generating a MD5 hash from a char[]

Tags: java, security, hash, md5

I found a solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30560830/generating-an-md5-hash-with-a-char/).

```
private byte[] toBytes(char[] chars) {
    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(chars);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(charBuffer);
    byte[] bytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(byteBuffer.array(),
            byteBuffer.position(), byteBuffer.limit());
    Arrays.fill(charBuffer.array(), '\u0000'); // clear sensitive data
    Arrays.fill(byteBuffer.array(), (byte) 0); // clear sensitive data
    return bytes;
}

char[] stringChars = "String".toCharArray();
byte[] stringBytes = toBytes(stringChars);

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(stringBytes);
String stringHash = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);

Arrays.fill(stringChars, '\u0000');
Arrays.fill(stringBytes, (byte) 0);
```

But it seems to have a bug, I can't figure out where or how it happens.

The problem is this part I think:

```
String hashedPass = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
```

The output of above code gives for String:

```
String = "9a9cce201b492954f0b06abb081d0bb4";
Correct MD5 of above string = "0e67b8eb546c322eeb39153714162ceb",
The code above though gives = "e67b8eb546c322eeb39153714162ceb";
```

It seems leading zeros of a MD5 are missing.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/421696/369) suggests simply left-padding with zeros - I don't know if there's a better solution.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Thank you very much for linking that post, it seems to have a lot of different (working) solutions for the problem. Is one more secure than another?

Comment: If you're using MD5 for something that needs to be secure, you should switch algorithms. What are you actually doing with these hashes?

Comment: Those are mostly stored hashes to communicate between a server via http post, of values just the client and the server know, so they can communicate in a "secure way" without implementing an encryption. I havent found a way yet to implement a https communication. I already changed MessageDigest to SHA1 though, because it's meaningless anyway.

Comment: So they're basically used as GUIDs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use `BigInteger` for this task, just write a method for converting byte arrays to hex strings.

```
static String hexEncode(byte [] data) {
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : data) hex.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    return hex.toString();
}

String hash = hexEncode(md.digest());
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this now : StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); for (byte b : digest) {sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));} This fixes the leading zero problem too. Not sure how to use code in these comments... this is really annoying.