# Securely decoding a Base64 character array in Java

Tags: java, security, char, base64, decode

I need to decode a [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) char array without converting it to a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). The char array is a password, and for security reasons I am not allowed to convert it to a String (this requirement is non-negotiable).

The [java.util.Base64.Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html).[decode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#decode-byte:A-) method accepts `byte[]`, [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), and [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), but not `char[]`.

**Security concerns of using a String to store sensitive data**

*per Jim Archer's comment*

- Strings are immutable
- They can only be purged from memory by the Garbage Collector (which cannot be forced to do it)

Comment: You can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9670279/1361506) to convert your `char[]` into a `byte[]` without an intermediate `String`, and then invoke `decode(byte[])`.

Comment: Why is the decoding method using a byte array unsuitable?

Comment: BTW, in case you (or anyone reading) does not know, the security issue arises from the fact that (1) Strings are immutable and (2) they hang around waiting for the GC to reclaim them, and you can't force the GC to do it. StringBuffer, on the other hand, solves this problem because you can destroy the contents when you're done with it.

Comment: @JimArcher How do you destroy the contents of the `StringBuffer`? Can the same be done with a `CharBuffer`? `CharBuffer` has a `clear()` method but it is not guaranteed to delete the contents. Part of my question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513144/converting-char-to-byte/9670279#9670279

Comment: @Roland Here are two ways off the top of my head:  sb.delete(0, sb.length());   and sb.setLength(0);   The setLength method will set the contents to \u0000.

Comment: @Roland also, as you said, the clear() method of CharBuffer DOES NOT destroy or overwrite the data, it just resets the internal pointer.  Don't use this for data that must remain secure, use StringBuffer and it's setLength() method instead. I just looked through the docs and didn't see a way to guarantee data destruction with a CharBuffer.

Comment: @JimArcher clearing a `XXXXBuffer` like `CharBuffer`:  `Arrays.fill(charBuffer.array(), (char) 0);` works only if the `CharBuffer` is backed by an array.

Comment: @JimArcher I just looked into the `StringBuffer` doc. `setLength` will only set new characters to '\u0000' if you are *increasing* the length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [CharBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap-char:A-) backed by the `char[]`. Then use [Charset.encode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#encode-java.nio.CharBuffer-) to encode the byte buffer into a [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). A ByteBuffer is accepted by the [Base64 Decoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html).

```
private static final java.util.Base64.Decoder BASE_64_DECODER = new java.util.Base64.getDecoder(); // Initializes a Decoder instance with getDecoder() method

private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";// Use the correct encoding here.

private byte[] decodePassword(char[] password) {
    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(password);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName(ENCODING).encode(charBuffer);
    return BASE_64_DECODER.decode(byteBuffer);
}
```

Inspired by azurefox's comment and the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9670279/1361506

Comment: How do I know which character encoding set to use? It isn't specified in the current implementation.

Comment: @Groppe What is the source of the text?

Comment: It is a password supplied by  PasswordCallback.getPassword (javax.security.auth.callback), which is populated in the interface by user input.

Comment: @Groppe I'm not sure. My guess is that it uses the encoding that was used in the form post. You can set that to be UTF-8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/708942/284685

Comment: Oh, wow... it's interesting how decode(ByteBuffer) works without copying but encode(ByteBuffer) does not. I had assumed that because encode() wasn't handling it securely, the same would be the case for decode() as well. But I guess things don't have to be completely symmetrical.

Comment: The BASE_64_DECODER should be declared like this:

private static final java.util.Base64.Decoder BASE_64_DECODER = java.util.Base64.getDecoder();