# How to encode `char[]` without converting to String

Tags: encoding, char, byte

I'm trying to preserve the `password` as `char[]` but in the second step, I'm converting it to a String again. Is there a way to to this in a better way?

```
char[] password = {'g', 'r', 'e'};
String toEncode = username + new String(password);
byte[] encoding = Base64.encodeBase64(toEncode.getBytes(Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())));
```

One option would be:

```
char[] toEncode = username.toCharArray() + password;
byte[] encoding = Base64.encodeBase64(new String(toEncode).getBytes(Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())));
```

**What I'm asking is is there a better way to achieve it without using `new String()`**

Comment: @Michael it's more: how to turn a char array to byte array without an intermediate step turning it to String

Comment: @jhamon that's what I'm suggesting, I'm asking is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What I'm asking is is there a better way to achieve it without using `new String()`

Comment: The 2nd answer is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513144/converting-char-to-byte/9670279#9670279

Comment: @Michael I know, I reported the dupe. But it looks like OP didn't read the correct answer

Comment: @SachiDangalla Why did you remove the Java tag? It's objectively related to Java.

Comment: Yes, the second answer best describes the solution to my question, but that question is too broad.