# Convert char hex array to byte array java

Tags: java, arrays, hex

How can I convert a char array of hex to byte array in Java?
I don't want to convert char array to string for security reasons.

Is there any inbuilt library available for this conversion in Java 8?

Comment: What do you mean? How does security is compromised if converted to `String`?

Comment: I can clear the char array by Arrays.fill but if converted to string it will be dependent on gc in java

Comment: You might want to [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9670279/5413565)

Comment: @Mushif Ali Nawaz See [Why is char array preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting char\[\] to byte\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513144/converting-char-to-byte)

Comment: Do you mean that each char value is a hexadecimal digit?  Meaning, ASCII `0`–`9` or `a`–`f` or `A`–`F`?

Comment: @VGR yes the char array is randomly generated hexadecimal array I have to convert it to byte array, I tried Bytebuffer bytebuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(Charbuffer.wrap(chrarr)) but this is just doing the utf8 conversion not hex conversion

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single Java SE method for it, but with [Character.digit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,int%29) it’s fairly straightforward:

```
byte[] parse(char[] hex) {
    int len = hex.length;
    if (len % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Even number of digits required");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        int high = Character.digit(hex[i], 16);
        int low = Character.digit(hex[i + 1], 16);
        bytes[i / 2] = (byte) (high << 4 | low);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```