# how to convert char[] to byte[] without creating any intermediate String

Tags: java, string, char, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting char array into byte array and back again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931854/converting-char-array-into-byte-array-and-back-again)

I have a password in `char[]` and i want this password in `byte[]` without creating any `String`. Please suggest the best possible way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Have you tried to [search existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[java]%20%2bchar[]%20%2bbyte[])?

Comment: Could you please explain why you don't want any `String`s involved?

Comment: i did google. but not found anyuseful.

Comment: @Tichodroma its a password in char[] if i convert this to string it will be there in memory but if its byte[] or char[] i can clear it up as soon as my work is done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If ASCII or ISO-8859-1 encoding is all you need you can copy one char at a time.

```
char[] chars = ...
byte[] bytes = new byte[chars.length];
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
    bytes[i] = (byte) chars[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any build in tool to do that. You may want to create a utility class that solve the issue for you.

```
public static byte[] charToByte(char[] array) {

  byte[] result = new byte[array.length];

  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result[i] = (byte) array[i];
  }

  return result;
}
```

How ever this solution is limited by encoding you are using.